# Unable to create a CloudFormation stack to create a Volume from AWS Backup for FsxN

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Getting an error `Cannot render the template because of an error.: YAMLException: bad indentation of a mapping entry at line 9, column 7: Name:` while creating a Volume Via CloudFormation from AWS BACKUP using a `backupID`.

I am referring to [AWS Doc for Fsx](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-fsx-volume.html)

```
---
Description: "This is Cloudformation template to Create Volme from backup FSxN."
Resources:      
  OntapVolumeFromBackupWithAllConfigs:
    Type: "AWS::FSx::Volume"
    Properties:
    BackupId: "74fe2af2-6815-494c-a4de-53d8188e3a5c"
      Name: "RestBackupFSxVolume01"
      OntapConfiguration:
        JunctionPath: "/RestBackupFSxVolume01"
        SecurityStyle: "UNIX"
        SizeInMegabytes: 41
        StorageEfficiencyEnabled: True
        StorageVirtualMachineId: "svm-0524816479dbbe473"
        TieringPolicy:
          CoolingPeriod: 42
          Name: "AUTO"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BackupId` should be a property, and the properties of `OntapConfiguration` should be strings:

```
Resources:      
  OntapVolumeFromBackupWithAllConfigs:
    Type: "AWS::FSx::Volume"
    Properties:
      BackupId: "74fe2af2-6815-494c-a4de-53d8188e3a5c"
      Name: "RestBackupFSxVolume01"
      OntapConfiguration:
        JunctionPath: "/RestBackupFSxVolume01"
        SecurityStyle: "UNIX"
        SizeInMegabytes: "41"
        StorageEfficiencyEnabled: "true"
        StorageVirtualMachineId: "svm-0524816479dbbe473"
        TieringPolicy:
          CoolingPeriod: 42
          Name: "AUTO"
```

Comment: Thank @Paolo.. this is fixed however it running a error now `1 validation error detected: Value 'backup-74fe2af2-6815-494c-a4de-53d8188e3a5c' at 'backupId' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: ^(backup-[0-9a-f]{8,})$ (Service: AmazonFSx; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequest; Request ID: ddf482ac-0966-4686-91d4-797c298db54c; Proxy: null)`

Comment: @microncloud your backup id is incorrect. that's a different issue; please open a different question